# edit row and columns in R

Tags: r, sorting, merge, expression, transform

I want to do this:
Input:

[image]

For the output i want to have the GTEX id as rows and ENSG as columns.
Like this:

> SAMPLEID                             ENSGO ENSGO ENSGO
> GTEX-1117F-022~                         0    187    0
> GTEX-1117F-042~                         0    109    0

I tried to do this command but it doesn't give me the correct output:

```
GTEx_Analysis <- as.data.frame(t(GTEx_Analysis_2017_06_05_v8_RNASeQCv1_1_9_gene_reads))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With base R

```
df_new <- data.frame(t(df[,-c(1:2)]))
colnames(df_new) <- df$Name
```

Or with `tidyverse`:

```
library(tidyverse)

  df_new <- df %>%
    select(-Description) %>%
    rowid_to_column() %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(Name, rowid)) %>%
    pivot_wider(names_from = c("Name", "rowid"), values_from = "value")

  colnames(df_new) <- str_replace_all(colnames(df_new), "\\_[0-9]","")
```

**Output**

```
                ENSG0~ ENSG0~ ENSG0~
GTEX-1117F-022~      0    187      0
GTEX-1117F-042~      0    109      0
```

Another option if you need to keep the `Description` would be to combine the `Name` and `Description` in the column heading.

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(-c(Name, Description)) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = c("Name", "Description"), values_from = "value")

  name            `ENSG0~_DDX11L1` `ENSG0~_WASH7p` `ENSG0~_MIR6859-1`
  <chr>                      <dbl>           <dbl>              <dbl>
1 GTEX-1117F-022~                0             187                  0
2 GTEX-1117F-042~                0             109                  0
```

**Data**

```
df <- structure(list(Name = c("ENSG0~", "ENSG0~", "ENSG0~"), Description = c("DDX11L1", 
"WASH7p", "MIR6859-1"), `GTEX-1117F-022~` = c(0, 187, 0), `GTEX-1117F-042~` = c(0, 
109, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

Comment: I used the third command that you gave: It does work and the output looks like:                                     ` Name Description GTEX-1117F-022~ GTEX-1117F-042~
1 ENSG0~     DDX11L1               0               0
2 ENSG0~      WASH7p             187             109
3 ENSG0~   MIR6859-1               0               0
`
But I want to do it for the entire file. There are 2604 rows. and I want to do it for the entire rows.

Comment: I tried to do the tidyverse one. but it gave an error. could not find the function pivot_longer. I have installed and loaded the package tidyverse

Comment: @RheaBedi Both the base R function and the `tidyverse` functions will work for your whole dataframe; just replace `df` with `GTEx_Analysis_2017_06_05_v8_RNASeQCv1_1_9_gene_reads`. Generally, on SO, you want to give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example), which you can do with `dput()`. So, I just made a small example here. In your expected output, you dropped the `Description` column so I did as well. One option would be to paste both the `Name` and `Description` together as the column name.

Comment: @RheaBedi Did you get an error when you did `library(tidyverse)`? `pivot_longer` is a part of `tidyr`. So, you could try explicitly loading `tidyr` and see if you are getting an error. I just double-checked on my end and it runs fine. I'm running R version 4.1.2 and Rstudio version 2021.09.2

Comment: Yes, I was able to do it using base R function. With tidyverse it still gave me error as pivot_longer not found even though I installed and loaded tidyr as well as tidyverse package.

Comment: @RheaBedi Hmmm, not sure then. You could try being explicit with the function, i.e., `tidyr::pivot_longer`. If that doesn't work, then it might have something to do with the version. What version of R are you running?